# How to select all nodes between 2 sibling nodes Xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

HTML:

```
<div class="article_content">
     <div><img src="....jpg" alt="...">
          <span class="caption">Source</span>
     </div>
<p>Sub Title Text</p>               
<p>Yes</p>                          
<p>Yes</p>              
<p>Yes</p>      
<p>Yes</p>          
<p>Yes</p>                      
<p><strong>No</strong> </p> 
<hr>
<p class="additional">No</p>
<ul class="menu_list">
   <li><a href="...">No</a></li>
   <li><a href="...">No</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to get everything marked as yes.

That is between:

```
article[@class="article-body"]/div[@class="ctx_content"]/div[@id="article_container"]/div[@class="article_column"]/p[1]
```

and:

```
//article[@class="article-body"]/div[@class="ctx_content"]/div[@id="article_container"]/div[@class="article_column"]/p/strong
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combination of [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) and [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) check:

```
//article[@class="article-body"]/div[@class="ctx_content"]/div[@id="article_container"]/div[@class="article_column"]/p[following-sibling::p/strong and position() > 1]
```

Comment: Can you explain this, it is selecting all sibling nodes of the paragraph tag, that has a position greater than the first one found. How are you excluding the strong?

Comment: @StevieG sure, `position()` here is just for skipping the first `p` with `Sub Title Text` text. `following-sibling` helps to get all the `p` tags before the one having `strong` as a child. Hope that makes sense.